# Is there a graceful way to use os.path.join() when the right-hand side may be /-prefixed?

Tags: python, python-2.7

In the code below, `context._arguments['ConfigFile']` returns a string like `'/path/file.py'` (which I can't change) but due to the way `os.path.join()` works, I need to remove at bare minimum the first /.

Note: In my use case `__file__` will always be in the appropriate position away from the config file.

I also considered giving it `context._arguments['ConfigFile'][1:]` but I think it's less robust.

```
config_file = os.path.join(
  os.path.dirname(os.path.abspath(__file__)), 
  *context._arguments['ConfigFile'].split(os.path.sep))
```

I expected there to be something a little more graceful, but maybe handling paths just never is. I am using Python 2.7 but for completeness I'm open to hearing Python 3 answers.

Comment: Have you considered `'./' + context._arguments['ConfigFile']` as the right-hand argument?

Comment: Not sure what happens on Windows, but `'.' + os.path.sep + path` neuters leading `/` on others.

Comment: (shouldn't actually need to use `os.path.sep` when generating paths to be consumed by other `os.path` functions; Python honors `/` even on Windows, so it's generating paths for use external to the Python interpreter where the distinction matters).

Comment: Do you use Python 2 or 3?

Comment: @CharlesDuffy: I avoid Windows, but out of morbid curiosity, what does Python do in `os.path.join` with paths that start with `'C:'`?

Comment: `/path/file.py` is technically an absolute path and join is meaningless in that case. So I don't think there is a more graceful way than what you are already doing.

Comment: I am using Python 2 @DariusMorawiec and I will look into the usage of ./ of __file__ that's a good point. More about the unpacking the split of the ```/path/file.py```is what I think is really gross

Comment: @torek, I don't have a Windows box handy (it's been a long while since I gained familiarity with the above-referenced behavior), but looking at `ntpath.py` from the standard library of Python 2.7.15, it looks like there's a `splitdrive()` function used to identify the drive subset of the path, and `join()` calls that function and honors any drive letter returned thereby, thus treating paths that specify them an absolute.

Comment: Also @torek it seems that the ```'/path/file.py'``` seems to still destroy the``` '.' + os.path.sep``` maybe that is what you meant when you said it neuters it?

Answer (score 1):

If you use Python 3, you can benefit from the `pathlib` package:

```
from pathlib import Path

file_path = '/path/file.py'

config_file = Path(__file__).parent / file_path.lstrip('/')

print(config_file)
# /Users/darius/repos/stackoverflow/questions/path/file.py
```

If you use Python 2, you can install `pathlib2` (`pip install pathlib2`) which is a backport of the standard `pathlib` package. To match the module names you can rename the import with `import pathlib2 as pathlib`.

Answer (score 1):

(This is a response to a comment, really, but needs formatting.)

```
>>> os.path.join('/a', '/b/c')
'/b/c'
>>> os.path.join('/a', './/b/c')
'/a/.//b/c'
```

Use `os.path.normpath` to clean up:

```
>>> os.path.normpath(os.path.join('/a', './/b/c'))
'/a/b/c'
```

The other way to view this is that, at least on Unix systems, `os.path.join` starts with its first argument.  Then, for each additional argument, it either *concatenates* or *replaces* using the return-value-so-far and the extra path component:

```
def unix_style_join(*args):
    "low quality version, for illustration"
    ret = args[0]
    for extra in args[1:]:
        if extra.startswith('/'):
            ret = extra
        else:
            ret = ret + '/' + extra
    return ret
```

Since your problem is that `context._arguments['ConfigFile']` starts with `/`, we merely need a variant of `context._arguments['ConfigFile']` that *means the same thing* but *does not start with `/`* ... and `./<whatever>` means the same as `<whatever>` except that `./<whatever>` starts with `.`, even if `<whatever>` starts with `/`.

The reason I didn't suggest this as the whole answer is that I have no idea how this all works on Windows.